# camera plugin captured image not showing in the html page

Tags: ionic3, angular4-forms

I am working on `ionic 3` mobile application, in which I wanted to capture the photo with the camera. I have installed the camera plugin. Following is the  html code:

```html
<ion-content padding>

    The world is your oyster.    

    <button ion-button (click)="capture_image()">Capture Image</button>
    <p align="center">
        <img src="{{myphoto}}" />
    </p>

</ion-content>
```

Following is the ts code:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

    myphoto:any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private camera: Camera) {

    }

    capture_image(){
        const options: CameraOptions = {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
        }

        this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
            // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
            // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
            //let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
            this.myphoto = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
        }, (err) => {
            // Handle error
        });
    }
}
```

My captured image is not showing in the `HTML` page.

Comment: you are asking for `FILE_URI`..  and you are setting `data:image/jpeg;base64`..

Comment: what does console.log(this.myphoto) show?

Comment: console.log(this.myphoto) prints data:image/jpeg;base64,file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/cache/1541136670468.jpg

Comment: `data:image/jpeg;base64` is attached to data_uri not file_uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling the app that you want the fileURI `file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/cache/1541142956953.jpg` instead of a base64 string via:

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
        }
```

So change that to:

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
        }
```

Which will return the base64 string that you're looking for.

Now You have to import the angular DomSanitizer to get around unsafe resource errors.

```
import {DomSanitizer}                      from '@angular/platform-browser';
...

constructor(private DomSanitizer: DomSanitizer){}



sanatizeBase64Image(image) {
    if(image) {
      return this.DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(image);
    }
  }
```

**Then in your `page.html`**

```
<img [src]="sanatizeBase64Image(myphoto)" onError="this.onError=null;">
```

Answer (score 0):

please replace img html tag  line i hope this will work

```
<img [src]="myphoto" />
```

to

```
<img src="{{myphoto}}" />
```

Comment: WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value data:image/jpeg;base64,file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/cache/1541142956953.jpg (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss) vendor.js:37231
Failed to load resource unsafe:data:image/jpeg;base64,file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/cache/1541142956953.jpg

Comment: please try to remove <p> tag in your html

Comment: Do not add 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' as you are using FILE_URI